# Javascript functions with optional first parameter, but passed second parameter

Tags: javascript, function

Let's say I have a function `myfunc` that can take up to two parameters: `arg1` and `arg2`:

```
var myfunc = function (arg1,arg2) {
  console.log(arg1,arg2);
};
```

I want to call the function using only `arg2`. However, when I run this, the input is passed to the first argument, and `myfunc` will log `"input" undefined` rather than `undefined "input"` as expected.

```
myfunc(arg2 = 'input')
> "input" undefined
```

Does Javascript support this type of input?

Comment: do you have a use case for this?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? The question is clear, he attempts something, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Javascript does not support named parameters. Pass an object if you want something similar.

Comment: If arg1 and arg2 are known types distinct from one another, you could use `function (...args)` so you can handle them from the array `args`

Comment: you could use `if (argument.length === 1) [arg1, arg2] = [arg2, arg1];` where you check the length of the handed opver parameters and swap the arguments.

Comment: You could do something like 

function callWithPositions(f, args) {
    const realArgs = Array(Math.max(Object.keys(args)) + 1).fill(0).map((_, i) => args[i]);
    f(...realArgs);
}

callWithPositions(myFunc, { 1: "input" });

Comment: @NinaScholz I have an array that I want to access either by the index number, or by a field associated with each object in the array. So swapping the arguments wouldn't work either, since I also want to allow passing only `arg1`.

Comment: @jane so both parameters are optional and you could call the function with either one or both of them? Are you sure you want to use a single function and/or two parameters for this? It seems like you probably want two different functions or at the very least a parameter *object* which has two optional fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript doesnot support the parameters with name. But you can achieve same thing using 
[Unpacking fields from objects passed as function parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) and passing object to function

```js
var myfunc = function ({arg1,arg2}) {
  console.log(arg1,arg2);
};

myfunc({arg2:"input"})
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this but it does the job!

Answer (score 2):

By doing `myFunc(arg2 = 'input)` you're doing:

```
arg2 = 'input'
myFunc(arg2)
```

Solutions to make it works can be:

```js
var myfunc = function (arg1='foo',arg2) {
  console.log(arg1,arg2);
}
myfunc('bar', 'input') 
myfunc(undefined, 'input')
```

Another solution is to use object

```js
var myfunc_es5 = function (opts) {
  opts = opts || {}
  console.log(opts.arg1,opts.arg2);
}
var myfunc_es6 = function ({arg1, arg2}) {
  console.log(arg1,arg2);
}
myfunc_es5 ({arg1: 'foo', arg2: 'bar'}) 
myfunc_es6 ({arg1: 'foo', arg2: 'bar'}) 
myfunc_es5 ({arg2: 'bar'}) 
myfunc_es6 ({arg2: 'bar'})
```

Comment: @trincot you right, i didn't know why I write this. it's object deconstructing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to act like you passed nothing to `arg1`, pass `undefined`.

Arguments are assigned `undefined` when nothing is passed to them.

This works with default arguments:

```
var func = function(a = 5){return a};
func(undefined); //5
```